# Adding rows to a DataTable from the result of a Query

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, ado.net

I am trying to do a simple process but can't seem to make it work properly. Please take into account that I am new at this and learning without any assistance except for mostly SO posts.

I want to query a SQL Server table and then append the retrieved record to a `DataTable`. Here is what I have so far:

ASPX:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtScan" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />

        <asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server" Text="SEARCH" OnClick="btnSearch_Click" />
    </div>
```

CS:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AddItem();
    }

    protected void AddItem()
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["2008DB"].ConnectionString))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

            cmd.Connection = conn;
            cmd.CommandText = "select * from items where ID = @lookup";
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@lookup", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = btnSearch.Text;
            da.Fill(dtScans); //I shouldn't be filling this I don't think?

        }
    }
}
```

I have confused myself as to the following:

1) Where to put `DataTable dtScans = new DataTable();`

2) How to properly read the records from the database and then append them to `dtScans`. I have used `SqlDataAdapter.Fill()` method before. Is this appropriate here?

3) Once this is figuered out I will make the `DataTable` the `DataSource` for a `GridView`

I've learned a lot from you guys but I am having problems on this one stitching all of it together. Thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 1):

First - it would be worth your time to familiarize yourself with the ADO.NET framework. There is good documentation in MSDN. This is a pretty basic ADO task, but it's not the only way to go. You can start here for information about datatables: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t31h6yhs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

That said, you're close!  You need to create a new `DataTable` instance and then you can fill it, like you said.  It can go right in your `AddItem()` method if you're just going to use it once.  Once it's filled you can bind it to your `GridView`.

```
protected void AddItem()
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["2008DB"].ConnectionString))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.CommandText = "select * from items where ID = @lookup";
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@lookup", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtScan.Text; //You'll also want to fix this line to use the TextBox instead of the Button

        DataTable dtScans = new DataTable(); //Create the new DataTable so you have something to fill
        da.Fill(dtScans);
        GridView1.DataSource = dtScans; //Set the DataTable to be the sourse for a GridView
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks OK I have it this far -- what if I want to keep taking input for new items and append them to dtScans? This is where I am really stuck. I'm stuck re-using the DataTable to add additional items to it. Thanks for your assistance @squillman